# A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

All was working fine yesterday but today when I opened jupyter notebook in conda environment, it was throwing error;

"A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."

In the Anaconda promt I can see the following;

```
To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///C:/Users/r.saroj/AppData/Roaming/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-7852-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=599ce568ac528d059ec077148c47715cab483852377acb58
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=599ce568ac528d059ec077148c47715cab483852377acb58
[W 11:11:57.501 NotebookApp] Notebook JJs Farm.ipynb is not trusted
Bad address (bundled\zeromq\src\epoll.cpp:100)
[I 11:11:58.464 NotebookApp] Kernel started: c24ae9e4-b0c1-422d-b88d-0e0351fbfe7a, name: python3
Bad address (bundled\zeromq\src\epoll.cpp:100)
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\r.saroj\Desktop\Power wind data\Script_JJ\env\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
Bad address (bundled\zeromq\src\epoll.cpp:100)

(C:\Users\r.saroj\Desktop\Power wind data\Script_JJ\env) C:\Users\r.saroj\Desktop\Power wind data\Script_JJ>    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\r.saroj\Desktop\Power wind data\Script_JJ\env\lib\threading.py", line 910, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\r.saroj\Desktop\Power wind data\Script_JJ\env\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\iostream.py", line 81, in _thread_main
    self.io_loop.start()
  File "C:\Users\r.saroj\Desktop\Power wind data\Script_JJ\env\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
    self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
  File "C:\Users\r.saroj\Desktop\Power wind data\Script_JJ\env\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 596, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "C:\Users\r.saroj\Desktop\Power wind data\Script_JJ\env\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1854, in _run_once
    event_list = self._selector.select(timeout)
  File "C:\Users\r.saroj\Desktop\Power wind data\Script_JJ\env\lib\selectors.py", line 324, in select
    r, w, _ = self._select(self._readers, self._writers, [], timeout)
  File "C:\Users\r.saroj\Desktop\Power wind data\Script_JJ\env\lib\selectors.py", line 315, in _select
    r, w, x = select.select(r, w, w, timeout)
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Please advise.

Comment: How are you starting the notebook? Is it in a conda environment?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @TonyLiu sorry, yes I started it in conda environment. I tried twice reinstalling anaconda but no luck.